# Fetching a redirect's target URL in OpenRefine

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302, openrefine

I have a CSV of ~2000 URLs that, when queried, do a 301 or 302 redirect, and I'm trying to figure out if OpenRefine is able to export to a new column the destination url that it retrieves HTML from when I fetch the html from it (or some other way).

e.g.

```
https://www-istp.gsfc.nasa.gov/stargaze/Ssolsys.htm
```

redirects to

```
https://pwg.gsfc.nasa.gov/stargaze/Ssolsys.htm
```

And I know that from clicking the link in my browser of choice. I've found a few answers suggesting that this can be done in various coding languages, but nothing so far suggesting how to do so in OpenRefine, even though I'm like 80% sure that it can be.

Does anyone out there know what I might be able to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenRefine you can write expressions in [GREL](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/expressions), [Jython](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/jythonclojure#jython) (Java Implementation of Python 2) and [Clojure](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/jythonclojure#clojure).
As far as I know GREL does not support analyzing the target of a redirection URL, so I would use Python for that.

In your OpenRefine Project go to your column containing the urls and use "Edit column" > "Add column based on this column..."

In the corresponding dialog window (see Screenshot below) you change the expression language to "Python / Jython" and use the following code snippet to retrieve the "real" URL of the request.

```py
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(value)
return response.geturl()
```

[image: Screenshot of OpenRefine dialog for adding a new column with the target URL.]

Comment: Aren't you importing urllib2 for each and every URL in the list? Or is OR smart enough to load it only once and only iterate on the response and return clauses? In other words, how this this perform on a list of 2000 URL's?

Comment: Checking the Jython integration in OpenRefine I suspect that it will call urllib2 for each and every URL in the list. But considering the context (http requests) this is not the bottleneck of this code snippet. Making http requests is... actually it would also be good practice to add a throttle between each request to avoid being perceived as a DDos attack.

Comment: Having used it a couple of times now, b2m is correct in that the get is the bottleneck rather than the code. I ended up adding a column to the csv I'm going through with an random int and then sorting by that before fetching the urls to try and minimize any single server getting more than one or two requests per every few seconds, also broke up the 2k-long csv into chunks of 300.

Comment: Good points. For me, the go-to solution (now confirmed) would have been a Python script, not OpenRefine. But I know a bit of Python. I am aware that might be a hurdle for some who don't.